# python sympy How do I simplify an expression where I know that a certain variable is an odd integer

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, simplification

Given, for example, the expression `(3*cos(pi*n/2)+2*sin(pi*n/2))/n**2` and the knowledge that n is a positive odd integer (ie 1,3,5,...), the expression could simplify to `2*(-1)**((n-1)/2)/n**2` because the `cos(pi*n/2)` terms all go to zero, and the `sin(pi*n/2)` terms go to -1 or +1.  Is there any way I can make sympy recognise this fact and perform the simplification?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `n` to be `odd`:

```
In [72]: n = Symbol('n', odd=True)                                                                                                             

In [73]: (3*cos(pi*n/2)+2*sin(pi*n/2))/n**2                                                                                                    
Out[73]: 
      n   1
      ─ - ─
      2   2
2⋅(-1)     
───────────
      2    
     n
```

Comment: Thanks - perfect.  Your reply has prompted me to find a full list of  possible assumptions.